# AJAX post data containing another post url

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Normally, when you make a post, the data looks something like this: "var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3", but I want my url var to contain a post url in itself. With that said, ajax interprets the value that I want to be in the url variable as separate variables and values. In my run.php script, I want to be able to grab $_POST["url"], and not have to grab $_POST["fish"] and $_POST["dog"] as well.

Also, I can't just concatenate the variables in run.php because the variable names will vary...

```
var dataString = 'url=http://somewhere.com/tuna?fish=x&dog=y';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/php/run.php",
    data: dataString,
    ...
});
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Let me know if further explanation is needed -- I'm having a hard time explaining this, as you can tell.

Comment: what is exactly you wan to do?

Comment: Could you please develop this question a bit better?

Comment: All I saw was Tuna Fish and now I'm hungry ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var dataString = 'url=http://somewhere.com/tuna?fish=x&dog=y';

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/php/run.php",
data: {url:dataString},
dataType: "json",
success:function(data){
  res = $.parseJSON(data);
  if(res.reply == 1)
    alert('I got the url');
  else
    alert('Something went wrong');
},
});
```

In your php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['url'] != '')
  echo json_encode(array('reply'=>1));
else
  echo json_encode(array('reply'=>0));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; I'll try it out. However, if I did have other variables that I wanted to post along with the url variable, how would I implement that? Is it even possible? Thanks.

Comment: yes it possible, in the "data" line: `data:{url:dataString,another:another_val},`, then in your php just use the "another" identifier into your post e.g. echo $_POST['another']. this will output the value of the "another_val".